# Register Windows mailto protocol to custom website URL

Tags: windows, registry, mailto

How can I register Windows 7's `mailto` protocol to open up a specific website *and* pass the address correctly? I'm *not* asking about using a specific browser (that is *Default Programs* for those wondering).

> www.example.com/mail/compose?to=crazypants@example.com

Answer (score 0):

Found the documentation for Firefox at least...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers#Registering

If someone finds out the answer at the operating system level that would be more desirable however.